# php mysql : how to avoid multiple connections to database in a Class?

Tags: php, pdo

Here is my index.php

```
<?
require("Annonce.php");
$annonce = new Annonce();
$annonce->id=1;
$annonce->delete();

?>
```

My Annonce.php is!

```
<?php 

require("DB.php");
class Annonce extends DB {
}    
 ?>
```

and finally DB is:

```
<?php 
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=annonces;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);


class DB {
    public static $debug = true;    
    function __construct() {
        # code...
    }
    function delete() {
        $id = $this->id;
        $table = get_class($this);
        $sql="delete from $table where id=$id";     
        if ($this::$debug) echo $sql;

    }

    function get() {
        $sql="select *...";
    }

}
 ?>
```

I don't know what is the best strategy to define the $db connection ?

If I define it inside DB class, it will make a connection any time an "Annonce" object is created. Maybe using $db as GLOBAL  (which I think is not clean)

Any suggestion for that ?

Comment: Maybe you will be interested by the [Singleton pattern](http://php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.patterns.php).

Comment: Or the Dependency Injection Container Pattern

Answer (score 1):

Create a Singleton ,some thing like this:

```
class DB
{
   private $_db;
   private $_instance;
   private function __construct() 
   {

    $this->_db = $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=annonces;charset=utf8', 'root', '');

}

public static function getInstance()
{
    if(!(self::$_instance instanceof DataBase)){
      $c = __CLASS__;
      self::$_instance = new $c;
    }
    return self::$_instance;
}
//.....other code

}
```

use it by :

```
$db = DB::getInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define your connection as a service and use a Dependency Injuection Container (DIC) to provide the connection for any other feature/module/class needing it by providing the Dependency Injection Container. Pimple is a [simple DIC Solution](http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/) by "the people who brought us Symfony".

Having a DIC is a good idea anyway.

THis might seem "over the top" for your problem (*since a Singleton would definetly solve your problem*) but considering a DIC will improve your work a lot more. And you asked for a clean Solution. The Singleton Design Pattern is only clean if you do not use Unit Tests since Singletons will [get you into trouble with mocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876951/why-is-it-hard-to-unit-test-singletons).

[Read more about it here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).